# Matching std::optional<bool> with Clang AST

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-tidy

I'm trying to write a clang-tidy check for `std::optional<bool> r = 5` to catch implicit conversions to bool.

```
|-DeclStmt <line:4:5, col:30>
| `-VarDecl <col:5, col:29> col:25 r 'std::optional<bool>':'std::optional<bool>' cinit
|   `-ExprWithCleanups <col:29> 'std::optional<bool>':'std::optional<bool>'
|     `-ImplicitCastExpr <col:29> 'std::optional<bool>':'std::optional<bool>' <ConstructorConversion>
|       `-CXXConstructExpr <col:29> 'std::optional<bool>':'std::optional<bool>' 'void (int &&) noexcept(is_nothrow_constructible_v<bool, int>)'
|         `-MaterializeTemporaryExpr <col:29> 'int' xvalue
|           `-IntegerLiteral <col:29> 'int' 5
```

So far, I have `match implicitCastExpr(hasDescendant(cxxConstructExpr()))` where I'm matching for an implicitCastExpr with a cxxConstructoExpr. The problem is I want to narrow the match on cxxConstructExpr to find only cases where bool is the template argument. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `cxxConstructExpr(...)`, you also need to use `hasType`, `classTemplateSpecializationDecl`, `hasTemplateArgument`, `refersToType`, and `booleanType`.

Here is a shell script invoking `clang-query` that finds implicit conversions to `std::optional<bool>` from a type other than `bool`:

```
#!/bin/sh

query='m
  implicitCastExpr(                              # Implicit conversion
    hasSourceExpression(                         # from a
      cxxConstructExpr(                          # constructor expr
        hasType(                                 # whose type is
          classTemplateSpecializationDecl(       # a template specialization
            hasName("::std::optional"),          # of std::optional
            hasTemplateArgument(                 # with template argument
              0, refersToType(booleanType())     # bool,
            )
          )
        ),
        unless(                                  # unless
          hasArgument(                           # the constructor argument
            0, expr(                             # is an expr with
              hasType(                           # type
                booleanType()                    # bool.
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )'

clang-query -c="$query" "$@"
```

(I use a shell script so I can format the query expression and add comments.)

Test input `test.cc`:

```
// test.cc
// Test clang-query finding implicit conversions to optional<bool>.

#include <optional>                    // std::optional

void f()
{
  std::optional<bool> r = 5;           // reported

  std::optional<int>  s = 6;           // not reported

  std::optional<bool> t = false;       // not reported
}

// EOF
```

Invocation of the script (saved as `cmd.sh`):

```
$ ./cmd.sh test.cc -- --std=c++17 

Match #1:

[...path...]/test.cc:8:27: note: "root" binds here
  std::optional<bool> r = 5;           // reported
                          ^
1 match.
```

I used Clang+LLVM-14.0.0, although I don't think I've used anything particularly recent here.

Figuring out these match expressions can be quite difficult.  The main reference is the [AST Matcher Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html), but even with that, it often requires a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. The comments explaining each matcher in English was especially helpful!